# How to add last modified date to google sheets file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a film list on google sheets and I want to add a script that puts the current date whenever I check/uncheck the tickbox or make any changes in the B column.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

I have tried doing a simple =now command whenever i edited the a,b column, it was able to put the current time whenever i edited the columns but when I opened the file the next day, the dates were changed to the current day so it was useless.

Answer (score 0):

From your provided Spreadsheet and your question, I believe your goal is as follows.

- When columns "A" and "B" of "Films" sheet are edited, you want to put the fixed timestamp to column "D" using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Google Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Films" || !(range.columnStart == 1 || range.columnStart == 2) || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 4).setValue(new Date());
}
```

- When you edit column "A" or "B", the script is automatically run and the timestamp is put into column "D".

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: it gives an error saying "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined."

Comment: @Aldalómë Thank you for replying. About `it gives an error saying "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined."`, when `onEdit` is directly run with the script editor, such an error occurs. So, I'm worried that you might have directly run the function of `onEdit`. In this case, when you edit column "A" or "B", the script is automatically run and the timestamp is put into column "D". So, please edit the cell value of columns "A" or "B".

Comment: @Aldalómë From `I want to add a script that puts the current date whenever I check/uncheck the tickbox or make any changes in the B column.` in your question, I proposed like that. In this case, the script is automatically run by editing the cells. In your situation, the columns "A" or "B" are edited, the script is run. So, please test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const sheetname="Films";

  if(col == 1 && row >1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == sheetname) {
  const currentdate = new Date();
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(currentdate);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  
  // Check if the changes are in column A
  if (range.getColumn() === 1) {
    // Get the row and column of the modified cell
    var row = range.getRow();
    var col = range.getColumn();
    
    // If a value in column A is modified
    if (col === 1) {
      // Set the current date in column D for the modified row
      sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

here you can change the column

range.getColumn() === 1

this is responsible for the column in which the date is to be entered

sheet.getRange(row, 4)

in this case, it looks for a checkbox marked True in column A and adds a date in parallel in column D

To add this script to a Google Sheets, follow these steps:

1. Open the Google Sheets where you have the list of movies.
2. Click on the "Tools" menu and select "Script editor". A new window with the script editor will open.
3. In the script editor, clear any existing code and paste the above script.
4. Click on the "File" menu and select "Save" to save the script.
5. Close the script editor window.
6. Now, the script will run every time you check/uncheck a checkbox or make changes in column B in the sheet, and the current date will be automatically added to column C for the corresponding row.

Please note that in order for the script to work properly, you need to have edit permissions in the Google Sheets.

```js
=IF(OR(A2="", A2=FALSE), "", TODAY())
```

Or here's a formula that works similarly

[image]

Comment: there's an error message saying "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')"

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @Aldalómë
the error pops up in the console because the script runs when editing any cell enter this script, save and select any cell in column A
////
tchrist
 I don't use artificial intelligence, I just work in an environment that every person must know what a given script is for because I work with id***s